# Bower folder is not found in vendor folder in yii2 basic application

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2

I had downloaded a basic yii2 application.And then pushed into git.But then in other pc I installed all the dependencies using a composer. But I dont have bower folder now so getting error:

> `The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\jumpbyte-site\vendor\bower/jquery/dist'`

My composer.json file has following require dependencies:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "himiklab/yii2-sitemap-module": "*"
    },
```

Comment: Did you install `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` ?

Comment: No I have not installed.What is use of this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To manage bower and npm package dependencies through Composer, you need to install (globally) [fxp/composer-asset-plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/fxp/composer-asset-plugin) :

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer install
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer

Comment: Don't forget about `composer install` after

Comment: I had the same issue using: `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0"` you want to make sure you are using `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`

Answer (score 4):

first download the default dependencies

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

then just run

```
composer install
```

then reload your site.

Answer (score 1):

Goto /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php.

Goto line 456.

Change

> Yii::setAlias('@bower', $this->_vendorPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bower');

to

> Yii::setAlias('@bower', $this->_vendorPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bower' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bower-asset');

Comment: And then what ?, never update the composer or yii framework in you whole life. changing the core script is never recommended

Answer (score 1):

This may break something later but this was much quicker than trying to root out the composer issue. I tried that too to no avail. I just deciced to give it what it was asking for.

If someone knows why this workaround is not good, please speak up.

**Goto /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php.**

```
    public function setVendorPath($path)
{
    $this->_vendorPath = Yii::getAlias($path);
    Yii::setAlias('@vendor', $this->_vendorPath);
    Yii::setAlias('@bower', $this->_vendorPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bower-asset'); //it was just 'bower'
    Yii::setAlias('@npm', $this->_vendorPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'npm');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(for fresh installation)
On Windows.

1. Remove the composer on windows and reinstall.
   after that
2. `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`
3. `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application`

(for update):
remove the contents on directory:

1. vendor remove the file
2. composer.lock than
3. `composer install`

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the old version of composer-asset-plugin and it didn't work properly. Only updating helps me. So update to the last version of composer-asset-plugin:

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`

Look at `^1.2.0`. It's important.

Then do this commands:

```sh
rm -rf vendor/*
rm composer.lock
composer install
```